# Passing dynamic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I'm experimenting with templates and I wrote this simple class method:

```
void Decimal::toBinary(size_t bits) {
    // decimalNumber being a class private variable (long double)
    std::bitset< bits > result(decimalNumber);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

I'm trying to pass `size_t bits` function argument to the bitset template.

According to [C++ Bitset Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) the implementations takes indeed a size_t argument:

```
template < size_t N > class bitset;
```

However, I'm getting

```
src/decimal.cc:11: error: ‘bits’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
src/decimal.cc:11: error: template argument 1 is invalid
src/decimal.cc:11: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
```

I suppose I'm not able to do this... any workarounds?

Comment: Depending on what type `decimalNumber` is, you might be able to get away with just having a long enough `std::bitset` that it will be able to hold all the information.

Comment: decimalNumber is long double

Comment: You can't "pass dynamic template arguments". These need to be known at compile time.

Comment: Ever tried casting ´bits´ to ´const´?

Comment: @LucasHoepner: That wouldn't help in the slightest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are a compile-time feature, not a run-time feature. If the number of different sizes you are going to support is limited, e.g., because you support 8, 16, and 32 bits, you can `switch` and delegate:

```
template <size_t bits>
void Decimal::toBinary() {
    std::bitset< bits > result(decimalNumber);
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
void Decimal::toBinary(size_t bits) {
    switch (bits) {
    default: throw std::runtime_error("number of bits not supprted");
    case  8: this->toBinary< 8>(); break;
    case 16: this->toBinary<16>(); break;
    case 32: this->toBinary<32>(); break;
    }
}
```

BTW, [don't use `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/). If you really mean to flush the stream use `std::flush`.